# Как передать картинку методом cURL?

Tags: php, post, curl, файлы, upload

Не знаю, как так вышло, но не могу передать картинку на сервер ВКонтакте. Вот собственно запрос:

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 90);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);//тут урл, взятый с запроса photos.getUploadServer
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array("file1" => '@'.urlencode($caption).';type=image/png'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1);
    $ans = curl_exec($ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

В ответ приходят все данные, кроме `photo_list`, который - `[]`.
В инфо показывает, что файл не передаю - `Upload_Content_Length` - 23.

Но почему, я не могу понять. Прошу помощи. Заранее спасибо!

**P.S.** Менял `Content-type` на `multipart`, отправлял с `@` и без нее, отправлял с `urlencode` и без, c `';type=image/png'` и без.

Еще пробовал `POSTFIELDS` делать так:

`'file1=@'.urlencode($caption).'; type=image/png'`, опять же с разными параметрами.

`$caption` содержит полный путь к файлу(на компе), путь берется с функции сканирования папки, плюс я выводил постфилдс, здесь ошибки не может быть.

Comment: Какая версия php?

Comment: _P.S. Менял Content-type на multipart, отправлял с @ и без нее, отправлял с urlencode и без, c ';type=image/png' и без._

Comment: Для загрузки файла должно быть `Content-Type: multipart/form-data`. `urlencode` уберите.

Comment: Уберите строку `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, `

Comment: Версия 5.3.8, обновиться возможности нет, поэтому не предлагайте.

Comment: Я извиняюсь, прошу помощи и еще и недоволен чем-то, но я ниже вопроса написал, что я пробовал. 

Без curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, тоже пробовал.

Comment: `Content-Type:` в данном случае самостоятельно прописывать не надо, curl сам установит нужное значение, которое будет также содержать `boundary=`

Comment: Включите `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1); ` и покажите вывод.

Comment: Хм. У меня магический cURL. :)

Уже не первый раз, когда запрашиваю доп. информацию для дебаггинга, начинает все нормально работать. Параметры не менял(кроме urlencode и заголовков, решил сделать чистый тест, хотя до этого так пробовал).

Всем спасибо, проблема решена. :)

Answer (score 1):

Можно картинку перевести в BASE64 и отправить текстом

Comment: Нет, АПИ ВК не принимает Base64.

Answer (score 0):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, 0);
```